# How to generate a matrix of combinations

Tags: r, cross-join

I have 5 items each of which can take on the value of 1 or -1. I want to generate a matrix that consists of rows of the possible combinations. The order of the items does not matter and the order of the combinations does not matter. I know I could do this mechanically, but I thought that someone must know a shortcut to generating this matrix. I apologize if this is similar to other questions but none of the solutions I have found can be applied to this particular problem with my programming skills.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
expand.grid(c(-1,1), c(-1,1), c(-1,1), c(-1,1), c(-1,1))
```

Answer (score 23):

To generalize Greg's answer:

```
N   <- 5
vec <- c(-1, 1)
lst <- lapply(numeric(N), function(x) vec)
as.matrix(expand.grid(lst))
```

Answer (score 7):

Alternative from `data.table` package is slightly faster compared to `expand.grid`:

```
library(data.table)  
CJ(c(-1,1), c(-1,1), c(-1,1), c(-1,1), c(-1,1))
```

Comment: I think a more general solution would be `do.call(CJ, rep(list(c(-1, 1)), 5))`