# How to do cross join in R?

Tags: r, cross-join

How can I achieve a cross join in R ? I know that "merge" can do inner join, outer join. But I do not know how to achieve a cross join in R.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a matrix of combinations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993546/how-to-generate-a-matrix-of-combinations)

Comment: Within the `tidyverse` or more specifically the `dplyr` package you can simply do: `full_join(df1, df2, by=character())`

Comment: ```data.table::foverlapse```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Is it just `all=TRUE`?

```
x<-data.frame(id1=c("a","b","c"),vals1=1:3)
y<-data.frame(id2=c("d","e","f"),vals2=4:6)
merge(x,y,all=TRUE)
```

From documentation of `merge`:

> If by or both by.x and by.y are of length 0 (a length zero vector or NULL), the result, r, is the Cartesian product of x and y, i.e., dim(r) = c(nrow(x)*nrow(y), ncol(x) + ncol(y)).

Comment: Why `all`? Don't see how `all=FALSE` (default) would influence the outcome. Also note that `merge` sets `by.x = by.y = by = intersect(names(x), names(y)` so `x` and `y` may not share any column names (otherwise you will not get a cross join with default settings).

Comment: Not sure why this is the accepted solution. As pointed out in the comments, it doesn't work to give a cross-join for several use-cases.

Comment: Just FYI: this only works with data.frames and not with data.tables

Answer (score 65):

If speed is an issue, I suggest checking out the excellent `data.table` package.  In the example at the end it's ~90x faster than `merge`.

You didn't provide example data.  If you just want to get all combinations of two (or more individual) columns, you can use `CJ` (cross join):

```
library(data.table)
CJ(x=1:2,y=letters[1:3])
#   x y
#1: 1 a
#2: 1 b
#3: 1 c
#4: 2 a
#5: 2 b
#6: 2 c
```

If you want to do a cross join on two tables, I haven't found a way to use CJ().  But you can still use `data.table`:

```
x2<-data.table(id1=letters[1:3],vals1=1:3)
y2<-data.table(id2=letters[4:7],vals2=4:7)

res<-setkey(x2[,c(k=1,.SD)],k)[y2[,c(k=1,.SD)],allow.cartesian=TRUE][,k:=NULL]
res
#    id1 vals1 id2 vals2
# 1:   a     1   d     4
# 2:   b     2   d     4
# 3:   c     3   d     4
# 4:   a     1   e     5
# 5:   b     2   e     5
# 6:   c     3   e     5
# 7:   a     1   f     6
# 8:   b     2   f     6
# 9:   c     3   f     6
#10:   a     1   g     7
#11:   b     2   g     7
#12:   c     3   g     7
```

Explanation of the `res` line:

- Basically you add a dummy column (k in this example) to one table and set it as the key (`setkey(tablename,keycolumns)`), add the dummy column to the other table, and then join them.
- The data.table structure uses column positions and not names in the join, so you have to put the dummy column at the beginning.  The `c(k=1,.SD)` part is one way that I have found to add columns at the beginning (the default is to add them to the end).
- A standard data.table join has a format of `X[Y]`.  The X in this case is `setkey(x2[,c(k=1,.SD)],k)`, and the Y is `y2[,c(k=1,.SD)]`.
- `allow.cartesian=TRUE` tells `data.table` to ignore the duplicate key values, and perform a cartesian join (prior versions didn't require this)
- The `[,k:=NULL]` at the end just removes the dummy key from the result.

You can also turn this into a function, so it's cleaner to use:

```
# Version 1; easier to write:
CJ.table.1 <- function(X,Y)
  setkey(X[,c(k=1,.SD)],k)[Y[,c(k=1,.SD)],allow.cartesian=TRUE][,k:=NULL]

CJ.table.1(x2,y2)
#    id1 vals1 id2 vals2
# 1:   a     1   d     4
# 2:   b     2   d     4
# 3:   c     3   d     4
# 4:   a     1   e     5
# 5:   b     2   e     5
# 6:   c     3   e     5
# 7:   a     1   f     6
# 8:   b     2   f     6
# 9:   c     3   f     6
#10:   a     1   g     7
#11:   b     2   g     7
#12:   c     3   g     7

# Version 2; faster but messier:
CJ.table.2 <- function(X,Y) {
  eval(parse(text=paste0("setkey(X[,c(k=1,.SD)],k)[Y[,c(k=1,.SD)],list(",paste0(unique(c(names(X),names(Y))),collapse=","),")][,k:=NULL]")))
}
```

Here are some speed benchmarks:

```
# Create a bigger (but still very small) example:
n<-1e3
x3<-data.table(id1=1L:n,vals1=sample(letters,n,replace=T))
y3<-data.table(id2=1L:n,vals2=sample(LETTERS,n,replace=T))

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(merge=merge.data.frame(x3,y3,all=TRUE),
               CJ.table.1=CJ.table.1(x3,y3),
               CJ.table.2=CJ.table.2(x3,y3),
               times=3, unit="s")
#Unit: seconds
#       expr        min         lq     median         uq        max neval
#      merge 4.03710225 4.23233688 4.42757152 5.57854711 6.72952271     3
# CJ.table.1 0.06227603 0.06264222 0.06300842 0.06701880 0.07102917     3
# CJ.table.2 0.04740142 0.04812997 0.04885853 0.05433146 0.05980440     3
```

Note that these `data.table` methods are much faster than the `merge` method suggested by @danas.zuokas.  The two tables with 1,000 rows in this example result in a cross-joined table with 1 million rows.  So even if your original tables are small, the result can get big quickly and speed becomes important.

Lastly, recent versions of `data.table` require you to add the `allow.cartesian=TRUE` (as in CJ.table.1) or specify the names of the columns that should be returned (CJ.table.2).  The second method (CJ.table.2) seems to be faster, but requires some more complicated code if you want to automatically specify all the column names.  And it may not work with duplicate column names.  (Feel free to suggest a simpler version of CJ.table.2)

Comment: Not sure if this is due to subsequent package changes, but to get this working I had to amend the function slightly to `CJ.table<-function(X,Y) setkey(X[,c(k=1,.SD)],k)[Y[,c(k=1,.SD)],allow.cartesian=TRUE][,k:=NULL]`

Comment: You're correct @StephLocke, the `data.table` behavior has changed since my original answer.  I've updated it and added some timings.  Thanks.

Comment: variant that makes sure the dummy variable name used is unique: `CJ.table.3 <- function(X,Y){
  unique_name <- last(make.unique(c(colnames(X),colnames(Y),"k")))
  X[,c(setNames(1,unique_name),.SD)][Y[,c(setNames(1,unique_name),.SD)],on=unique_name,allow.cartesian=TRUE][,(unique_name):=NULL]
}`

Comment: During a recent update data.table does no longer allow for the latter version, but instead throws an error. adding `allow.cartesian` alleviates this, but data.table suggests using the `by = .EACHI`. Note that all three methods provide almost exactly the same speed as of today (benchmarking provides around 35 miliseconds on my machine for all 3 methods over 1000 replications), as such there is no performance benefit over the less readable version `CJ.table.2`. (with the added allow.cartesian argument)

Comment: Is there a version faster than CJ.table.1 that works on data table?  I have a problem of a massive scale so even a small improvement saves a lot of time!

Comment: @dnlbrky can this extended for more than two data.tables? Both CJ.table.1 and CJ.table.2 are not working for me, but "res" does. thanks

Comment: Noting that this no longer works in the most up to date version of data table

Answer (score 23):

This was asked years ago, but you can use `tidyr::crossing()` to do a cross-join. Definitely the simplest solution of the bunch.

```r
library(tidyr)

league <- c("MLB", "NHL", "NFL", "NBA")
season <- c("2018", "2017")

tidyr::crossing(league, season)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 2
#>   league season
#>   <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1 MLB    2017  
#> 2 MLB    2018  
#> 3 NBA    2017  
#> 4 NBA    2018  
#> 5 NFL    2017  
#> 6 NFL    2018  
#> 7 NHL    2017  
#> 8 NHL    2018
```

Created on 2018-12-08 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Better. The behavior you show (with vectors as inputs) is identical to the `base` function `expand.grid`. The advantage `crossing` has is that it works with `data.frame` inputs (and the point of the question). Using the example from the accepted answer, `x <- data.frame(id1 = c("a", "b", "c"), vals1 = 1:3);
y <- data.frame(id2 = c("d", "e", "f"), vals2 = 4:6)`, then `crossing(x, y)` works as expected, while `expand.grid(x, y)` fails.

Comment: This appears to be much faster than `merge()`

Answer (score 12):

If you want to do it via data.table, this is one way:

```
cjdt <- function(a,b){
  cj = CJ(1:nrow(a),1:nrow(b))
  cbind(a[cj[[1]],],b[cj[[2]],])
}

A = data.table(ida = 1:10)
B = data.table(idb = 1:10)
cjdt(A,B)
```

Having said the above, if you are doing many little joins, and you don't need a `data.table` object and the overhead of producing it, a significant speed increase can be achieved by writing a `c++` code block using `Rcpp` and the like:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix crossJoin(NumericVector a, NumericVector b){
  int szA = a.size(), 
      szB = b.size();
  int i,j,r;
  NumericMatrix ret(szA*szB,2);
  for(i = 0, r = 0; i < szA; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < szB; j++, r++){
      ret(r,0) = a(i);
      ret(r,1) = b(j);
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
```

---

### To compare, firstly for a large join:

C++

```
n = 1
a = runif(10000)
b = runif(10000)
system.time({for(i in 1:n){
  crossJoin(a,b)
}})
```

user  system elapsed 
  1.033   0.424   **1.462**

---

data.table

```
system.time({for(i in 1:n){
  CJ(a,b)
}})
```

user  system elapsed 
  0.602   0.569   **2.452**

---

### Now for lots of little joins:

C++

```
n = 1e5
a = runif(10)
b = runif(10)
system.time({for(i in 1:n){
  crossJoin(a,b)
}})
```

user  system elapsed 
  0.660   0.077   **0.739**

---

data.table

```
system.time({for(i in 1:n){
  CJ(a,b)
}})
```

user  system elapsed 
 26.164   0.056  **26.271**

Comment: Joining atomic vectors is quite different from joining data.frames. Basically, you simplified it to much. Neither `CJ` or your solution address the problem in question.

Answer (score 8):

Using `sqldf`:

```
x <- data.frame(id1 = c("a", "b", "c"), vals1 = 1:3)
y <- data.frame(id2 = c("d", "e", "f"), vals2 = 4:6) 

library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT * FROM x
      CROSS JOIN y")
```

Output:

```
  id1 vals1 id2 vals2
1   a     1   d     4
2   a     1   e     5
3   a     1   f     6
4   b     2   d     4
5   b     2   e     5
6   b     2   f     6
7   c     3   d     4
8   c     3   e     5
9   c     3   f     6
```

Just for the record, with the base package, we can use the  `by=NULL` instead of `all=TRUE`:

```
merge(x, y, by= NULL)
```

Answer (score 6):

By using the merge function and its optional parameters:

Inner join: merge(df1, df2) will work for these examples because R automatically joins the frames by common variable names, but you would most likely want to specify merge(df1, df2, by = "CustomerId") to make sure that you were matching on only the fields you desired. You can also use the by.x and by.y parameters if the matching variables have different names in the different data frames.

```
Outer join: merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "CustomerId", all = TRUE)

Left outer: merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "CustomerId", all.x = TRUE)

Right outer: merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "CustomerId", all.y = TRUE)

Cross join: merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = NULL)
```

Answer (score 4):

For *data.table* use

```
dt1[, as.list(dt2), by = names(dt1)]
```

Note that this only works if there are no duplicate rows.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I don't know of a built-in way to do it with `data.frame`'s but it isn't hard to make.</strike>

*@danas showed there is an easy built-in way, but I'll leave my answer here in case it is useful for other purposes.*

```
cross.join <- function(a, b) {
    idx <- expand.grid(seq(length=nrow(a)), seq(length=nrow(b)))
    cbind(a[idx[,1],], b[idx[,2],])
}
```

and showing that it works with some built-in data sets:

```r
> tmp <- cross.join(mtcars, iris)
> dim(mtcars)
[1] 32 11
> dim(iris)
[1] 150   5
> dim(tmp)
[1] 4800   16
> str(tmp)
'data.frame':   4800 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ mpg         : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl         : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp        : num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp          : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat        : num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt          : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec        : num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs          : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am          : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear        : num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ carb        : num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 5.1 5.1 5.1 5.1 5.1 5.1 5.1 5.1 5.1 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3.5 3.5 3.5 3.5 3.5 3.5 3.5 3.5 3.5 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.4 1.4 1.4 1.4 1.4 1.4 1.4 1.4 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd love to know if there exists a *convenient* way to crossjoin two data.tables. I do this so often I ended up rolling my own function that others may find helpful

```
library(data.table)

cartesian_join <- function(i, j){
  # Cartesian join of two data.tables
  # If i has M rows and j has N rows, the result will have M*N rows
  # Example: cartesian_join(as.data.table(iris), as.data.table(mtcars))

  # Check inputs
  if(!is.data.table(i)) stop("'i' must be a data.table")
  if(!is.data.table(j)) stop("'j' must be a data.table")
  if(nrow(i) == 0) stop("'i' has 0 rows. Not sure how to handle cartesian join")
  if(nrow(j) == 0) stop("'j' has 0 rows. Not sure how to handle cartesian join")

  # Do the join (use a join column name that's unlikely to clash with a pre-existing column name)
  i[, MrJoinyJoin := 1L]
  j[, MrJoinyJoin := 1L]
  result <- j[i, on = "MrJoinyJoin", allow.cartesian = TRUE]
  result[, MrJoinyJoin := NULL]
  i[, MrJoinyJoin := NULL]
  j[, MrJoinyJoin := NULL]

  return(result[])
}

foo <- data.frame(Foo = c(1,2,3))
foo
  Foo
1   1
2   2
3   3

bar <- data.frame(Bar = c("a", "b", "c"))
bar
  Bar
1   a
2   b
3   c

cartesian_join(as.data.table(foo), as.data.table(bar))
   Bar Foo
1:   a   1
2:   b   1
3:   c   1
4:   a   2
5:   b   2
6:   c   2
7:   a   3
8:   b   3
9:   c   3
```

Answer (score 1):

dplyr solution:

You can perform a cross-join within dplyr joins (i.e. `left_join`, `inner_join`, etc.).

For example, according to the `left_join` help:
"To perform a cross-join, generating all combinations of x and y, use `by = character()`"

So you could use something like:

```
df3 <- left_join(df1, df2, by = character())
```

Answer (score 0):

In `dplyr`, there is `cross_join`:

```r
library(dplyr)
A <- data.frame(id1=letters[1:3],vals1=1:3)
B <- data.frame(id2=letters[4:7],vals2=4:7)

cross_join(A, B)
```

output

```r
   id1 vals1 id2 vals2
1    a     1   d     4
2    a     1   e     5
3    a     1   f     6
4    a     1   g     7
5    b     2   d     4
6    b     2   e     5
7    b     2   f     6
8    b     2   g     7
9    c     3   d     4
10   c     3   e     5
11   c     3   f     6
12   c     3   g     7
```