# data.table versus tidyr::expand_grid

Tags: r, data.table, tidyr

I have

```
XIa <- diag(1, 3)
colnames(XIa) <- rownames(XIa) <- c("a0", "a1", "a2")
XIb <- diag(1, 2)
colnames(XIb) <- rownames(XIb) <- c("b0", "b1")
XIc <- diag(1, 2)
colnames(XIc) <- rownames(XIc) <- c("c0", "c1")
```

`tidyr::expand_grid` gives me:

```
tidyr::expand_grid(as.data.frame(XIa), as.data.frame(XIb), as.data.frame(XIc))
# A tibble: 12 x 7
      a0    a1    a2    b0    b1    c0    c1
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     0     0     1     0     1     0
 2     1     0     0     1     0     0     1
 3     1     0     0     0     1     1     0
 4     1     0     0     0     1     0     1
 5     0     1     0     1     0     1     0
 6     0     1     0     1     0     0     1
 7     0     1     0     0     1     1     0
 8     0     1     0     0     1     0     1
 9     0     0     1     1     0     1     0
10     0     0     1     1     0     0     1
11     0     0     1     0     1     1     0
12     0     0     1     0     1     0     1
```

How do I achieve the same result using `data.table`?

Clearly, there is this way:

```
dXIa <- data.table(XIa)
dXIb <- data.table(XIb)
dXIc <- data.table(XIc)

cbind(
  dXIa[c(rep(1:3, each = 4))],
  dXIb[c(rep(1:2, each = 2))],
  dXIc[c(rep(1:2, len = 12))]
)

    a0 a1 a2 b0 b1 c0 c1
 1:  1  0  0  1  0  1  0
 2:  1  0  0  1  0  0  1
 3:  1  0  0  0  1  1  0
 4:  1  0  0  0  1  0  1
 5:  0  1  0  1  0  1  0
 6:  0  1  0  1  0  0  1
 7:  0  1  0  0  1  1  0
 8:  0  1  0  0  1  0  1
 9:  0  0  1  1  0  1  0
10:  0  0  1  1  0  0  1
11:  0  0  1  0  1  1  0
12:  0  0  1  0  1  0  1
```

but that is probably not optimal/ideal.

Comment: Do any of the answers resolve your questions? If not, please comment or update your question with additional information. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CJ` but it does not work with `data.table` directly. Using the function `cjdt` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31893090/3962914) answer you can do -

```
library(data.table)

dXIa <- data.table(XIa)
dXIb <- data.table(XIb)
dXIc <- data.table(XIc)

cjdt <- function(a,b){
  cj = CJ(1:nrow(a),1:nrow(b))
  cbind(a[cj[[1]],],b[cj[[2]],])
}

Reduce(cjdt, list(dXIa, dXIb, dXIc))

#    a0 a1 a2 b0 b1 c0 c1
# 1:  1  0  0  1  0  1  0
# 2:  1  0  0  1  0  0  1
# 3:  1  0  0  0  1  1  0
# 4:  1  0  0  0  1  0  1
# 5:  0  1  0  1  0  1  0
# 6:  0  1  0  1  0  0  1
# 7:  0  1  0  0  1  1  0
# 8:  0  1  0  0  1  0  1
# 9:  0  0  1  1  0  1  0
#10:  0  0  1  1  0  0  1
#11:  0  0  1  0  1  1  0
#12:  0  0  1  0  1  0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to RonakShah's use of `cjdt`, here's a modified version that has two more features:

1. Guards against 0-row frames, which should really be a no-op for the 0-row frame;
2. Uses a single call to `cbind` instead of `Reduce`; while reduce isn't evil here, there may be benefits with a much longer list of frames/tables; and
3. While not a stated constraint here, it works with `data.frame` and `data.table` alike.

```r
cjdt2 <- function(...) {
  dots <- Filter(nrow, list(...))
  eg <- do.call(expand.grid, lapply(sapply(dots, nrow), seq_len))
  do.call(cbind, Map(function(x, i) x[i,], dots, eg))
}
cjdt2(XIa, XIb, XIc)
#    a0 a1 a2 b0 b1 c0 c1
# a0  1  0  0  1  0  1  0
# a1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0
# a2  0  0  1  1  0  1  0
# a0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0
# a1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0
# a2  0  0  1  0  1  1  0
# a0  1  0  0  1  0  0  1
# a1  0  1  0  1  0  0  1
# a2  0  0  1  1  0  0  1
# a0  1  0  0  0  1  0  1
# a1  0  1  0  0  1  0  1
# a2  0  0  1  0  1  0  1
```

Which you can easily wrap with `setDT` (either externally or mod the function).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach that uses `data.table` merge

```
expgridDT<-function(...) {
  DTs<-list(...)
  for(jj in 1:(length(DTs)-1)) {
    DTs[[jj+1]]<-merge(DTs[[1]][,c(kfjekflj=1,.SD)], DTs[[2]][,c(kfjekflj=1,.SD)],by=.EACHI, allow.cartesian=TRUE)[,!"kfjekflj",with=FALSE]
  }
  return(DTs[[length(DTs)]][])
}
```

Essentially what this does is create's a dummy column on each `data.table` with a non-sense name (`kfjekflj`) to make a collision with a real column name unlikely. It sets that dummy column as the join by column.  Then it merges two tables at a time with `allow.cartesian` turned on.  It does that for every `data.table` that is passed to the function.

Here's a benchmark:

```
XIa <- diag(1, 50)
colnames(XIa) <- rownames(XIa) <- paste0("a",1:ncol(XIa))
XIb <- diag(1, 72)
colnames(XIb) <- rownames(XIb) <- paste0("b",1:ncol(XIb))
XIc <- diag(1, 80)
colnames(XIc) <- rownames(XIc) <- paste0("c",1:ncol(XIc))

XIa <- as.data.table(XIa)
XIb <- as.data.table(XIb)
XIc <- as.data.table(XIc)
microbenchmark(expgridDT(XIa, XIb, XIc), Reduce(cjdt, list(XIa, XIb, XIc)), cjdt2(XIa, XIb, XIc))

Unit: milliseconds
                              expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
          expgridDT(XIa, XIb, XIc)   167.5827   191.6542   264.8172   203.8769   231.6937   852.2033   100
 Reduce(cjdt, list(XIa, XIb, XIc))   164.4640   217.2215   252.2262   230.7276   255.6974   689.1763   100
              cjdt2(XIa, XIb, XIc) 65611.1425 67829.0407 77024.1458 77151.0220 84385.0727 95048.6625   100
```