# Data frame row duplication in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I currently have a data frame that looks like

| Trial # | Header | Header 2 | Header 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1.1 | 1.2 |
| 2 | 2 | 2.1 | 2.2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3.1 | 3.2 |
| 4 | 4 | 4.1 | 4.2 |

And I need to add mutate the data frame so there is a year column and each trial repeats 3 times. Something that looks like:

| Trial # | Header | Header 2 | Header 3 | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1.1 | 1.2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1.1 | 1.2 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 1.1 | 1.2 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 2.1 | 2.2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2.1 | 2.2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 2.1 | 2.2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 3.1 | 3.2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 3.1 | 3.2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3.1 | 3.2 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 4.1 | 4.2 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 4.1 | 4.2 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 | 4.1 | 4.2 | 3 |

I am not sure how to go about accomplishing this so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df %>%
  mutate(year = list(1:3))%>%
  unnest(year)

# A tibble: 12 x 5
   Trial Header Header.2 Header.3  year
   <int>  <int>    <dbl>    <dbl> <int>
 1     1      1      1.1      1.2     1
 2     1      1      1.1      1.2     2
 3     1      1      1.1      1.2     3
 4     2      2      2.1      2.2     1
 5     2      2      2.1      2.2     2
 6     2      2      2.1      2.2     3
 7     3      3      3.1      3.2     1
 8     3      3      3.1      3.2     2
 9     3      3      3.1      3.2     3
10     4      4      4.1      4.2     1
11     4      4      4.1      4.2     2
12     4      4      4.1      4.2     3
```

Answer (score 2):

Very directly, you can do this:

```
result = original_data[rep(1:nrow(original_data, each = 3), ]
result$year = rep(1:3, times = nrow(original_data))
```

A little fancier, and more generalizable if you had additional columns you wanted combinations of, we can use `merge` to do a [cross join](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10600060/903061).

```
result = merge(original_data, data.frame(year = 1:3), all = TRUE)
```

Comment: I believe `merge(df, list(year=1:3))` should also work

Comment: When I do that, the resulting data frame is grouped by year. How do I get it so that it is grouped by trial number instead?

Comment: @PythonSOS No the data is in no way grouped. It is just arranged. Not grouped. and there is nothing wrong if arranged by year or Trial number. All the resulting computation will be the same. Just order it by Trial Number, ie `with(a<-merge(df, list(year =1:3)), a[order(Trial), ])`