# R - data.table join - column overwrite

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to left join between two data.tables using a condition (income>cost for example).
I need to this in data.table (and not say dplyr) due to efficiency as I'm working huge datasets.
My problem is, when I join using the following code, my "income" column gets overwritten with the values of the cost column.

Any suggestion to fix this behavior?

```
A <- data.table(ID=c(1,2,3,4),cost=c(1000,2000,3000,4000))
B <- data.table(income=c(1500,2500,3500,4500),name=c("A","B","C","D"))

#The output:
B[A,.(ID,cost,income,name),on=.(income>cost)
  ,allow.cartesian=TRUE
  ,nomatch=NULL]

#Expected output:
A <- A %>% mutate(ID_j=1)
B <- B %>% mutate(ID_j=1)

A %>% 
  left_join(B) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  filter(cost<income) %>% 
  select(-ID_j)
```

Used different libraries, but I need to make it work with data.table.

Comment: so just to be clear, the join is just literally all rows in the current row order?

Comment: We have 4 rows in one column and 4 in the other, joining all of A to all of B will give a data frame of 16 rows (4x4). I then filter to only have rows where the income in B is bigger than the cost in A, so the result is 10 rows.

If I do this using data.table, the result is 10 rows, but the column gets overwritten and columns cost and income are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
B[A, .(ID, cost, income = x.income, name), on = .(income > cost)]
```

**results**

```
    ID cost income name
 1:  1 1000   1500    A
 2:  1 1000   2500    B
 3:  1 1000   3500    C
 4:  1 1000   4500    D
 5:  2 2000   2500    B
 6:  2 2000   3500    C
 7:  2 2000   4500    D
 8:  3 3000   3500    C
 9:  3 3000   4500    D
10:  4 4000   4500    D
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the cross-join aspect (get your fill 16 rows) using a temporary key (k) then filter and drop the k column:

```
res<-setkey(A[,c(k=1,.SD)],k)[B[,c(k=1,.SD)],allow.cartesian=TRUE][income>cost,-c("k")]
```

adapted from: [How to do cross join in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600060/how-to-do-cross-join-in-r)

Comment: Is this efficient? This seems like just joining every row with every row, not using inequality to not give matches, and then filtering right?

Comment: No clue - definitely worth testing the timings with a larger dataset.  It may be possible to incorporate the comparison/filtering at the point of the intial join.