# Unique combination of all elements from two (or more) vectors

Tags: r, r-faq

I am trying to create a unique combination of all elements from two vectors of different size in R.

For example, the first vector is

```
a <- c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI")
```

and the second one is dates stored as strings currently

```
b <- c("2012-05-01", "2012-05-02", "2012-05-03", "2012-05-04", "2012-05-05")
```

I need to create a data frame with two columns like this

```
> data
    a          b
1  ABC 2012-05-01
2  ABC 2012-05-02
3  ABC 2012-05-03
4  ABC 2012-05-04
5  ABC 2012-05-05
6  DEF 2012-05-01
7  DEF 2012-05-02
8  DEF 2012-05-03
9  DEF 2012-05-04
10 DEF 2012-05-05
11 GHI 2012-05-01
12 GHI 2012-05-02
13 GHI 2012-05-03
14 GHI 2012-05-04
15 GHI 2012-05-05
```

So basically, I am looking for a unique combination by considering all the elements of one vector (a) juxtaposed with all the elements of the second vector (b).

An ideal solution would generalize to more input vectors.

---

> **See also:**
>   [How to generate a matrix of combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993546/how-to-generate-a-matrix-of-combinations)

Answer (score 179):

this maybe what you are after

```
> expand.grid(a,b)
   Var1       Var2
1   ABC 2012-05-01
2   DEF 2012-05-01
3   GHI 2012-05-01
4   ABC 2012-05-02
5   DEF 2012-05-02
6   GHI 2012-05-02
7   ABC 2012-05-03
8   DEF 2012-05-03
9   GHI 2012-05-03
10  ABC 2012-05-04
11  DEF 2012-05-04
12  GHI 2012-05-04
13  ABC 2012-05-05
14  DEF 2012-05-05
15  GHI 2012-05-05
```

If the resulting order isn't what you want, you can sort afterwards. If you name the arguments to `expand.grid`, they will become column names:

```
df = expand.grid(a = a, b = b)
df[order(df$a), ]
```

And `expand.grid` generalizes to any number of input columns.

Comment: And without needing `plyr` to just do a sort:
`result <- expand.grid(a=a,b=b);
result <- result[order(result$a,result$b),];`

Comment: is someone with more rep than me able to accept this answer?

Comment: If order and names should be as in the question: `expand.grid(b=b,a=a)[2:1]`

Comment: Note the title is Unique Combinations - this answer solves the OP problem, but if the 2 columns are of the same data type and you apply expand.grid, you will have unique permutations, not unique combinations

Answer (score 54):

The `tidyr` package provides the nice alternative `crossing`, which works better than the classic `expand.grid` function because (1) strings are not converted into factors and (2) the sorting is more intuitive:

```
library(tidyr)

a <- c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI")
b <- c("2012-05-01", "2012-05-02", "2012-05-03", "2012-05-04", "2012-05-05")

crossing(a, b)

# A tibble: 15 x 2
       a          b
   <chr>      <chr>
 1   ABC 2012-05-01
 2   ABC 2012-05-02
 3   ABC 2012-05-03
 4   ABC 2012-05-04
 5   ABC 2012-05-05
 6   DEF 2012-05-01
 7   DEF 2012-05-02
 8   DEF 2012-05-03
 9   DEF 2012-05-04
10   DEF 2012-05-05
11   GHI 2012-05-01
12   GHI 2012-05-02
13   GHI 2012-05-03
14   GHI 2012-05-04
15   GHI 2012-05-05
```

Comment: `expand.grid` has a `stringsAsFactors` argument that can be set to `FALSE`, which solves (1).

Answer (score 27):

Missing in this [r-faq](/questions/tagged/r-faq) overview is the `CJ`-function from the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table)-package. Using:

```
library(data.table)
CJ(a, b, unique = TRUE)
```

gives:

> ```
>       a          b
>  1: ABC 2012-05-01
>  2: ABC 2012-05-02
>  3: ABC 2012-05-03
>  4: ABC 2012-05-04
>  5: ABC 2012-05-05
>  6: DEF 2012-05-01
>  7: DEF 2012-05-02
>  8: DEF 2012-05-03
>  9: DEF 2012-05-04
> 10: DEF 2012-05-05
> 11: GHI 2012-05-01
> 12: GHI 2012-05-02
> 13: GHI 2012-05-03
> 14: GHI 2012-05-04
> 15: GHI 2012-05-05
> ```

---

<sub>NOTE: since version 1.12.2 `CJ` autonames the resulting columns (see also [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/3296) and [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3295)).</sub>

Answer (score 10):

Since version 1.0.0, `tidyr` offers its own version of `expand.grid()`. It [completes the existing family of `expand()`, `nesting()`, and `crossing()` with a low-level function that works with vectors](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2019/09/tidyr-1-0-0/).

When compared to `base::expand.grid()`:

> Varies the first element fastest. Never converts strings to factors.
>   Does not add any additional attributes. Returns a tibble, not a data
>   frame. Can expand any generalised vector, including data frames.

```
a <- c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI")
b <- c("2012-05-01", "2012-05-02", "2012-05-03", "2012-05-04", "2012-05-05")

tidyr::expand_grid(a, b)

   a     b         
   <chr> <chr>     
 1 ABC   2012-05-01
 2 ABC   2012-05-02
 3 ABC   2012-05-03
 4 ABC   2012-05-04
 5 ABC   2012-05-05
 6 DEF   2012-05-01
 7 DEF   2012-05-02
 8 DEF   2012-05-03
 9 DEF   2012-05-04
10 DEF   2012-05-05
11 GHI   2012-05-01
12 GHI   2012-05-02
13 GHI   2012-05-03
14 GHI   2012-05-04
15 GHI   2012-05-05
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use order function for sorting any number of columns. for your example

```
df <- expand.grid(a,b)
> df
   Var1       Var2
1   ABC 2012-05-01
2   DEF 2012-05-01
3   GHI 2012-05-01
4   ABC 2012-05-02
5   DEF 2012-05-02
6   GHI 2012-05-02
7   ABC 2012-05-03
8   DEF 2012-05-03
9   GHI 2012-05-03
10  ABC 2012-05-04
11  DEF 2012-05-04
12  GHI 2012-05-04
13  ABC 2012-05-05
14  DEF 2012-05-05
15  GHI 2012-05-05

> df[order( df[,1], df[,2] ),] 
   Var1       Var2
1   ABC 2012-05-01
4   ABC 2012-05-02
7   ABC 2012-05-03
10  ABC 2012-05-04
13  ABC 2012-05-05
2   DEF 2012-05-01
5   DEF 2012-05-02
8   DEF 2012-05-03
11  DEF 2012-05-04
14  DEF 2012-05-05
3   GHI 2012-05-01
6   GHI 2012-05-02
9   GHI 2012-05-03
12  GHI 2012-05-04
15  GHI 2012-05-05`
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R you could try merge(), cbind() and expand.grid().

```
a <- seq(1E4)
b <- c("2012-05-01", "2012-05-02", "2012-05-03", "2012-05-04", "2012-05-05")

 microbenchmark(
  "merge (1)" = mmm <- as.matrix(merge(a, b)),
  "diy (2)"   = {ccc <- cbind( rep(a, length(b)),
                               b[rep(seq_along(b), each = length(a))]
                        )
                },
 "diy R (3)"  = {ccc <- cbind( a,
                               b[rep(seq_along(b), each = length(a))]
                        )
                },
  "grid (4)"  = ggg <- expand.grid(a, b),
  times       = 2
)
```

Output.

```
Unit: milliseconds
      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 merge (1) 863.3100 863.3100 888.6573 888.6573 914.0046 914.0046     2
   diy (2) 117.1912 117.1912 142.1394 142.1394 167.0875 167.0875     2
 diy R (3)  34.9320  34.9320  49.4119  49.4119  63.8918  63.8918     2
  grid (4)  45.1876  45.1876  46.1592  46.1592  47.1308  47.1308     2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `rep` and the fact that base R data frames recycle:

```
data.frame(a = rep(a, each = length(b)), b = b)
```