# plot of non-parametric vs parametric 'prob' outcomes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am not able to plot for the aforesaid question on binary outcome.

Let

```
data=data.frame(feature1=c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10),rep(3,10)),
                feature2=c(rep(letters[1:2],15)),
                 Outcome=sample(0:1,30,replace = T))

ggplot(data,aes(feature1,Outcome)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = 'glm',method.args=list(family='binomial')) + 
  facet_wrap(~feature2)
```

here I get only points at 1s and 0s, But I want points at probabilities by non-parametric model.(i.e (Outcome==1)/(all Outcomes(0s and 1s) for a particular 'feature1' segregated by 'feature2')

I know I can form a column for required probabilities from NonParametric model, but it will be very tedious to do for all combination of 'facet_wrap' and 'aes'

Comment: I think my question is on 'Data Visualisation' - why putted on hold as off-topic?

Comment: For exactly the reason given: it is solely about programming.

Comment: @whuber can you, please, move this to 'Stack Overflow'.

Comment: how would your expected output column look like?

Comment: I'd recommend fitting a model outside of `ggplot2`. It's primarily a graphics package - use if for the graphing, not for the model fitting. There's no reason it needs to be tedious to assemble all combinations, of variables, just use `expand.grid`. [See here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11388371/903061)

Comment: Also, just as a note, a binomial GLM is *not* a non-parametric model.

Comment: @Jimbou my expected column mean(Outcome) per 'feature 1'(numeric) segregated by 'feature 2'(factor)

Comment: @Gregor I took GLM as parametric and "(Outcome==1)/(all Outcomes(0s and 1s)" as non-parametric.
expand.grid not fulfilling or maybe I can't utilize.

Comment: So you want to use the mean of `Outcome` at each facet/x-value? Just calculate the means: with `dplyr`: `group_by(data, feature1, feature2) %>% summarize(mean = mean(outcome))`. Lots of methods and examples at the [R-FAQ average data by group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/903061). You could probably also use `stat_summary(geom = "point", fun.y = mean)`. Is this what you're asking? If so, why the `glm` stuff in your question?

Comment: @Gregor 'stat_summary' is fulfilling my requirement, I used GLM to see how the GLM is fitting towards proportion of binary outcome...
just like we do fit model for regression Outcome, I tried to visualise for proportion of binary outcome.

Thank you very much!
Please write an answer, because online information is not available for that case.

Comment: Okay. In the future, please make your questions **minimal** - the GLM is great for you to do on your plot, but in this question it just confuses the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than "non-parametric model", I would call *(Outcome==1)/(all Outcomes(0s and 1s)* the *mean*. We can use `stat_summary` to summarize data with an arbitrary summary function, like `mean()`. In this case, I think you want

```
stat_summary(geom = "point", fun.y = mean)
```

Certain geoms, like `geom_boxplot`, are just clever uses of `stat_summary`.