# R generating panel data

Tags: r, dplyr, panel, tidyr

I have following three variables

```
id = c(1,2) 
year = c(90,91)
group = c('a','b')
```

What is the most efficient way to create the following dataframe structure ?

```
id year group
1   90    a
1   91    a
1   90    b
1   91    b
2   90    a
2   91    a
...
```

Comment: `expand.grid(id, year, group)` or `library(tidyverse);crossing(id, year, group)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unique combination of all elements from two (or more) vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388359/unique-combination-of-all-elements-from-two-or-more-vectors)